# How to insert and display grouped data together in a table

Tags: php, android, mysql, sql

I am developing a coffee ordering application in which i have 3 different tables

1. `main_menu` with fields `id`,`item_name` e.g. Cafe,Pizza bar,Breakfast etc.
2. `sub_menu` with fields `id`,`sub_item_name`,`item_name`,`price` e.g chai latte for $2.00
3. `sub_type` with fields `id`,`sub_item_type`,`sub_item_name`,`item_name`,`add_price` e.g. Chai latte large size(+ $0.50) and soy milk(+$0.50) so total price $3.00

What I am confuse with is that user may select more than one `sub_type` when ordering just like in the above example where he may want extra milk and size upgrade. So when I am inserting order into database, do i have to run the insert query twice when user selects `sub_type`? Or is there any way to do it in single query?

And same thing when I am displaying data in the kitchen side: how can i group the `sub_type` and display it in same row so that coffee maker don't get confused and easily know that that's the same order with extras?

i am using android at coffee ordering side and php for kitchen side display
i need displaying result in php table something like this

```
    +----------+-------------+---------------------+------------+
    | Order No |Item_name    |Sub_Item_Name        |Total Price |
    +----------+-------------+---------------------+------------+
    |145       |Chai Latte   |Soy Milk,Large Size  | $3.00      |
    |          |             |  Extra Sugar        |            |
    +-----------------------------------------------------------+
    |146       |Black Tea    |Regular Size,No      | $2.50      |
    |          |             |Sugar                |            |
    +-----------------------------------------------------------+
    |147       |Espresso     |Skin Milk,Small Size | $3.50      |
    |          |             |                     |            |
    +-----------------------------------------------------------+
```

Comment: Is `item_name` supposed to appear twice in `sub_type`?

Comment: @isim No item_name should be once but sub_item_type can be more than one selected by user for instance a user may select a espresso with large size,soy milk and 2 extra sugar.... so when i display it in kitchen side in single row with single item name espresso but more than on sub_item_type large size,extra sugar and soy milk should be displayed

Comment: @isim NO Its actually my mistake it should be like `sub_type` with fields `id`,`sub_item_type`,`sub_item_name`,`item_name`,`add_price`

Comment: You should be able to do this using SQL `JOIN` and some PHP codes to dynamically build the `WHERE` clause. What have you tried?

Comment: @isim i haven't tried anything yet, i am just displaying the order and inserting order one by one at the moment using `insert` query to insert data and `where` clause to get the data and display data in php

Answer (score 0):

Without trying to over complicate things, in my opinion, the orders should go into a separate `order` table with the fields you just specified i.e. `order_id`, `item_name`, `sub_item_name` and `total_price`. Each row can contain multiple comma-separated items in the `sub_item_name` field. (You can easily construct these using PHP codes). The `main_menu`, `sub_menu` and `sub_type` tables should be used to present menu and add-ons options to the customers. There are no needs to couple the `menu` tables with the `order` table.

With this schema, you will perform only one insertion for each order. And the same orders are presented to the kitchen staff without having to join or group any other tables.

Will this work?

Comment: I am doing something like what you suggested @isim .. i do have a separate `order` table and i do `insert` the data into table but at the moment if a user selects 3 extras than i have to run `insert` query for 3 times and at the time of display i am just displaying all row at the moment... i have no idea how to separate it with comma in php... my `order` table is 
`id`,`sub_item_type`,`sub_item_name`,`item_name`,`total_price` like this right now

Comment: @MikeRoss Are the extras stored in an array? If yes, you can use the PHP [implode](http://php.net/manual/en/function.implode.php) function to convert the array into a string using comma as a delimiter.